# Error calculating time difference in Python

Tags: python, python-datetime

Quick question. Does someone know why I'am getting an 'Invalid Syntax' error usign this code? Thank you all.

```
def get_time_difference(date, time_string):
    time_difference = datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(f"{date} {time_string}", "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
    return f"{time_difference.hour}:{time_difference.minute}"


get_time_difference(1-1-2020 1:50)
```

Comment: Missing quotation marks around the string.

Comment: It should be, ``get_time_difference('1-1-2020', '1:50')``

Comment: Thank you both, I received an other error which got fixed by @Edison Feneyab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `get_time_difference("1-1-2020", "1:50")`.

However, you will get another error:

```
AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

You can adapt `get_time_difference` as follows:

```py
def get_time_difference(date, time_string):
    time_difference = datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(
        f"{date} {time_string}", "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"
    )
    hours = time_difference.seconds // 3600
    minutes = time_difference.seconds // 60 % 60
    return f"{hours}:{minutes}"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime


def get_time_difference(date, time_string):
    time_difference = datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(f"{date} {time_string}", "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
    return f"{time_difference.seconds // 3600}:{time_difference.seconds // 60 % 60}"


print(get_time_difference('1-1-2020', '1:50'))
```

> Output

`15:50`

Comment: Thank you this worked fine. Where does the f actually stand for in the code?

Comment: This f is just for formatting, otherwise you can also return `str(time_difference.seconds // 3600) + ":" + str(time_difference.seconds // 60 % 60)`